# I want to filter by specific column name on Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, tuples, multiple-columns

I have a pandas dataframe where each column is a tuple when I do pd.dataframe().columns

```
[('5/12/2022', 'A', 'N', '001'),
 ('5/12/2022', 'B', 'N', '001'),
 ('5/12/2022', 'C', 'N', '002'),
 ('5/12/2022', 'E', 'N', '002'),
 ('5/12/2022', 'A', 'N', '002')]
```

I want to filter such that I only get the columns where the second entry of the tuple is == 'A'.
So that when I do pd.dataframe().columns, I get

```
[('5/12/2022', 'A', 'N', '001'),
 ('5/12/2022', 'A', 'N', '002'),....] as my columns.
```

I want to do it without manually inputting the columns because the dataframe has thousands of columns.

Comment: can you provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()`?

Answer (score 1):

A python list comprehension would tackle it:

```
select_columns = [col for col in df.columns if col[1] == 'A']
cut_down_df = df[select_columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really have tuples and not a MultiIndex, you can use the `str` locator

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str[1] == 'A']
```

example input:

```
idx = [('5/12/2022', 'A', 'N', '001'),
       ('5/12/2022', 'B', 'N', '001'),
       ('5/12/2022', 'C', 'N', '002'),
       ('5/12/2022', 'E', 'N', '002'),
       ('5/12/2022', 'A', 'N', '002')]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=idx, index=[0])
```

output:

```
  (5/12/2022, A, N, 001) (5/12/2022, A, N, 002)
0                    NaN                    NaN
```